# How to update topic branch with upstream changes on master?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I start some work on a topic branch

```
    •-•-• < topic
   /
•-•       < master
```

I push the topic branch

```
$ git push origin topic
```

Someone else pushes changes to master

```
    •-•-• < origin/topic
   /
•-•-•—•   < origin/master
```

#### How do I update my local master and rebase my topic?

History should look like this

```
        •-•-• < topic
       /
•-•-•—•       < master
```

#### What I am trying

```shell
; update master
$ git checkout master
$ git fetch origin
$ git merge --ff-only origin/master

; rebase topic
$ git checkout topic
$ git rebase master
```

#### The problem

All of my commits on `topic` are seen as uncommitted. So when I try `git push origin topic`, I get

```
 ! [rejected]        topic -> topic (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '/path/to/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

#### The solution?

Please note, I do **not** want to merge my `topic` branch with `master`. I'd simply like to get my local repo updated without having to merge branches unnecessarily.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let me rework your example for clarity.

```
    C-D-E < topic, origin/topic
   /
A-B < master, origin/master
```

Then someone does work.

```
    C-D-E < topic, origin/topic
   /
A-B-F-G < origin/master
  ^
master
```

You fetched F & G from origin, and then rebased topic onto master.  So now your repository looks like this.

```
    C-D-E < origin/topic
   /
A-B-F-G < master, origin/master
       \
        C'-D'-E' < topic
```

And this is the problem.  origin/topic at E can not be fast-forwarded to topic at E'.  Rebase is really only meant for commits that have not been pushed to origin.  Since you pushed C, D, and E to origin/topic already, you would have to rewrite history on the remote repository.  Hence the error.  So you really have three options:

1. Stop pushing a topical branch.  If it's only you who is working on topic, there's no need to push it.  Just keep rebasing topic on top of master, and when done, fast-forward merge master to topic & push master.  Delete local topic branch.  Voila!
2. Merge topic & master.  If you need to collaborate on a topical branch, you should probably suck it up and merge.
3. Force the remote rebase:

   git push origin topic -f

   This will force origin/topic to E'.  Except by re-writing history in the remote repository, you'll have fire and brimstone, human sacrifice, dogs and cats living together, mass hysteria... and your fellow developers not liking you very much.  Not recommended at all.

Comment: finally something that makes sense. thank you so much for your time <3

Comment: It is fairly common for topic branches to be rebased and then force-pushed. You need to make sure people understand your topic branch is your private history, which is mostly the case with GitHub forks, e.g.

Comment: I think #1 could maybe you use some tweaking. To @febeling's point, I think nowadays most corporate repos would prefer devs continuously push their WIP branches since it provides an automatic backup, and enables pull request collaboration suggestions from teammates. So rebasing *personal* branches and force pushing is pretty standard in a work setting.

Answer (score 5):

```
; update master
git checkout master
git pull --rebase origin master  

; rebase topic
git rebase master topic

; push topic (force)
git push -f origin topic
```

Comment: can you please provide an explanation ?

Comment: Explanation for what? This is a standard way to do it. Does it work?

Comment: My pull does exactly the same as you fetch & merge sequence. Than I just rebase in one command. You have to provide -f flag as history will be rewritten by rebase.

Comment: I am just having trouble visualizing what rebasing master on origin/master looks like... I guess I just don't understand, and I don't really want to run potentially dangerous commands on my repo without fully understanding them :S

Comment: If you don't have any changes in local master than rebasing master on top of origin/master will be just a fast-forward.

Comment: After I did this, my master branch says "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit." Why does it do this?

Comment: It seems like your local master has not-yet-pushed changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your question.

1. You will not get merge conflicts when you push. This can only happen when you merge, rebase, cherry-pick or stash pop/apply.
2. You **cannot avoid conflicts** if someone else is changing the same content as you are at the same time (even though it may be just you working on another copy of the repo).
3. "All of my commits on topic are seen as uncommitted" doesn't make sense. You probably mean that "all of the changes that my topic branch commits introduce" are not committed yet due to a conflict when I try to rebase.

Your steps are correct, except that you are ignoring that your rebase has stopped on a conflict and you are simply ignoring it. You must resolve your conflicts and then:

```
git add confilctedfile1.txt conflictedfile2.txt
git rebase --continue
```

You may need to do this for all of your commits in your topic branch. Only when the rebase is complete should you push.

Another note: For this reason, rebase is not the preferred workflow for day-to-day work. Merge is much easier and more accurate in what is happening with the code base. There are many reasons to favour merge over rebase.

Comment: 1). My mistake; I was getting a fast-forward error when trying to push. 2) I'm not talking about resolving conflicts where developers changed the same content. I just want my repos updated... this is so frustrating :S

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's you or another developer. To the repository, it looks like simultaneous changes. Please read about the DAG (directed acyclic graph) to see how git works.

Comment: It's **not** simultaneous changes... I even ran a test using two dummy repos and got the same result.

Comment: if there are no simultaneous changes, then you don't nee to rebase at all. Before changing code, git pull --ff-only.

Comment: "You will not get merge conflicts when you push. This can only happen when you merge, rebase, cherry-pick or stash pop/apply."   I think this occurs because topic & origin/topic have diverged.